# Send Email from Outlook using MS Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I have the following Visual Basic for Applications code on a MS Access Report.

I have the Outlook app open when I run the report.

I want to send an email if a value in the "Sequence Number" column in a MS Access "Comments" table equal 3276 in the "Parts.mdb" database.

The code doesn't give any errors but I'm not getting the email.

The complete code:

```vb
Option Compare Database

Option Explicit
Dim DB As Database
Dim wrkJet As Workspace
Dim CoeReportsDB As Database
Dim CommentsRS As Recordset
Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
Dim oMail As MailItem

Sub SendEmail()

    Set DB = CurrentDb()
    Set wrkJet = CreateWorkspace("", "admin", "", dbUseJet)
    Set CoeReportsDB = wrkJet.OpenDatabase("T:\Parts.mdb")
    
    Set CommentsRS = CoeReportsDB.OpenRecordset("Comments", dbOpenTable)
    CommentsRS.index = "Sequence Number"
    CommentsRS.Seek "=", 3276

    If Not CommentsRS.NoMatch Then
        Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
        Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        oMail.Body = "Sequence Number Out of Range"
        oMail.Subject = "Perform Sequence Number Reset."
        oMail.To = "someone@somewhere.com"
        oMail.Send
        Set oMail = Nothing
        Set oApp = Nothing
    End If
    
ShutDown:
    CommentsRS.Close
    Set DB = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Not actually your problem in this instance, but [Using parentheses in code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-parentheses-in-code) is probably worth a read...

Answer (score 1):

[The `Recordset.Seek` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-seek-method-dao) does **not return anything**.  Instead, it changes the `Index` property of the `Recordset` object, or the `NoMatch` property if the `Seek` cannot find any matching results.

The correct way to write that line would be as follows:

```
CommentsRS.Seek "=", 3276
If Not CommentsRS.NoMatch Then
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I made the change as you said but still I'm not getting the email. The code did not give any errors though.

Comment: Have you checked that the `if` statement is being validated? (e.g. by placing a `debug.print "Yes"` within the `then` argument)

Comment: @techindustry Please don't edit your question to invalidate existing answers like that - If will make it harder for other people with the same problem to find a solution!  Either put an addendum, query in a comment on the answer (like you have), or create a new question.